# What is difference between "you value the most" and "you value most"?

Tags: articles, superlatives

I have a sentance "...remember the purpose and principles you value most". How would it be different from "....value the most"?

Comment: There are a few similar questions, such as [this](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/46923/is-there-always-a-the-before-a-superlative-adjective). There's no difference in meaning.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Are "most" and "the most" the same?](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/18571/are-most-and-the-most-the-same) Also, more generally, [Is there always a "the" before a superlative adjective?](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/46923/is-there-always-a-the-before-a-superlative-adjective)